# Download files from mega.co.nz in java

Tags: java, file, url, download

Does anyone have any idea how to download files from mega.co.nz in java, because the urls are not directly downloadable because of the appearing dialog box.

e.g. the [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!CwpwhSzT!-T8VWSDqe6KkVYRlzecDlCPRZGIENu8XGNUWYuv-3iM) is not directly downloadable. Image of dialog box appearing: [image]

How can I download these files directly in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might fit your needs: https://github.com/Ale46/Mega-Java

The project is a complete mega api.